# How to run Telegram from Terminal

Tags: command-line, startup, telegram

So I have telegram messenger on my Ubuntu and I'm trying to launch it from terminal and later on set it up as startup program - problem is I cannot find command to run it. telegram/Telegram don't work.

This is how I installed this app:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/telegram
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install telegram
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The app is installed in

```
/opt/telegram/
```

and the binary is

```
/opt/telegram/Telegram
```

To start the messenger via command line, you have to use the full path or add the path to your PATH definition or create a symbolic link in `/usr/bin`:

- Use the PATH

  1. Edit the file `~/.profile`

     ```
     nano ~/.profile
     ```
  2. and add the line below at the end of the file

     ```
     export PATH="$PATH:/opt/telegram"
     ```

**OR**

- Use a symbolic link

  ```
  sudo ln -s /opt/telegram/Telegram /usr/local/bin
  ```

---

You have a desktop file:

```
/usr/share/applications/telegram.desktop
```

and therefore use the command below

```
cp /usr/share/applications/telegram.desktop ~/.config/autostart
```

to create an autostart entry via command line.

[image]

---

*Why do I know that?*

```
% dpkg -L telegram
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/telegram
/usr/share/doc/telegram/copyright
/usr/share/doc/telegram/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/telegram.desktop
/opt
/opt/telegram
/opt/telegram/telegram.tar.xz
/opt/telegram/telegram.svg

 % cat /usr/share/applications/telegram.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Telegram
Exec=/opt/telegram/Telegram
Comment=Network taking back our right to privacy.
Icon=/opt/telegram/telegram.svg
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;
```

Comment: Yes that do the trick :) - Thank you so much for support

Comment: I like the "why do I know that" additions...  **;-)**

Comment: Why the hell did they put it there instead of /usr/bin as all others?

Answer (score 9):

If you installed using snap, try

```
telegram-desktop
```

Comment: this outputs: `Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported`, any ideas?

Comment: it works for my ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 3):

Use a Bash alias like this:

```
alias tg='/opt/telegram/Telegram'
```

And then just type:

```
tg
```

in Terminal and it will open Telegram. You can replace `tg` with what you like.

Comment: Seems like a good answer to me

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TelegramTUI](https://github.com/bad-day/TelegramTUI) on your terminal