# The command for setting keyboard shortcut for tor browser or open it via terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard, shortcut-keys, tor

I wanted to set keyboard shortcut for tor browser.
So i need a command which opens tor browser.
I installed .tar.gz file of tor browser,which installed in my home directory:

```
/home/sina/tor-browser-linux
```

So the file which i should set keyboard shortcut is this directory:

```
/home/sina/tor-browser-linux/tor-browser_en-US/Tor\ Browser
```

I wanted to open tor browser via terminal in these way:

```
sina@msi:~$ ./home/sina/tor-browser-linux/tor-browser_en-US/Tor\ Browser
bash: ./home/sina/tor-browser-linux...: No such file or directory
```

I tried to solve it by reading this link(like i did it for telegram before):

> [How to run Telegram from Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667340/how-to-run-telegram-from-terminal)

I tried to do this for tor(instead of telegram):

```
sina@msi:~$ nano ~/.profile
```

I added this to the last line of `.profile`:

```
export PATH="/home/sina/tor-browser-linux/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser.desktop"
```

It didn't work!

```
sina@msi:~$ sudo ln -s /home/sina/tor-browser-linux/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser.desktop /usr/local/bin
sina@msi:~$ sudo ln -s /home/sina/tor-browser-linux/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser.desktop /usr/share/applications
sina@msi:~$ cp /usr/share/applications/start-tor-browser.desktop ~/.config/autostart
```

I tried this too:

```
sina@msi:~$ alias tor='/home/sina/tor-browser-linux/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser.desktop'
sina@msi:~$ tor
/usr/bin/env: ‘./Browser/execdesktop’: No such file or directory
```

When i cd to the tor browser's directory and run this command:

```
sina@msi:~/tor-browser-linux/tor-browser_en-US$ ./start-tor-browser.desktop
```

Tor browser opens and works...but when i run this:

```
sina@msi:~$ ./tor-browser-linux/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser.desktop
/usr/bin/env: ‘./Browser/execdesktop’: No such file or directory
```

I have start-tor-browser.desktop in my home directory,and i can open it with thunar,but not with terminal:

```
sina@msi:~$ ./start-tor-browser.desktop
/usr/bin/env: ‘./Browser/execdesktop’: No such file or directory
```

- Is there any command to open tor browser via terminal?

Comment: im a bit confused .. can you tell us what the executable file is called and where it is located exactly .. you have used 3 different names for the executable and I don't have a tor browser installed so I cant look at the directory structure myself

Comment: @JohnOrion tor browser is installed in this directory:`/home/sina/tor-browser-linux/tor-browser_en-US/Tor Browser` ...and the file name is **Tor Browser**

Comment: Please try to start it with this command: `/home/sina/tor-browser-linux/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser`. Unless you changed the directory structure or moved files around this should work, assuming you gave the correct path in your question… Moving the `.desktop` file will certainly *not* work, as it uses a relative path – and please don't do `export PATH=/some/path` in your `.profile` unless you know *very well* what you do.

Comment: Btw, info taken from my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985092/how-do-i-launch-tor-browser-on-specific-web-page-from-command-line/985202#985202).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path to run tor-browser is (taken from [start-tor-browser].desktop file)

```
[unzipped tar archive]/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach
```

p.s.: you didn't specify which desktop manager you have or which distro.

If you have LXDM/lightdm/lubuntu** then edit this file:

```
[homefolder]/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml
```

You will see lots of sections `<keybind>...</keybind>`; add underneath one of them your keybind like so:

```
<keybind key="C-A-T">
    <action name="Execute">
        <command>[path to where you unzipped the tar archive]/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach</command>
    </action>
</keybind>
```

Save and exit and run the following inside terminal:

```
openbox --reconfigure
```

**Edit**

Regarding Xfce shortcuts see these links:

- [Cannot change global keyboard shortcuts in Linux Mint XFCE - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152897/cannot-change-global-keyboard-shortcuts-in-linux-mint-xfce)

  Locate xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml and edit as needed.
- [Making Keyboard Shortcuts for Frequently Used Applications - Manjaro Linux](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=XFCE:Making_Keyboard_Shortcuts_for_Frequently_Used_Applications)

  Panel, Applications -> Settings -> Keyboard. Open the Application Shortcuts T and add the shortcut and app as needed.

Comment: i have ubuntu 17.10 xfce

Comment: and i don't have openbox directory in .config

Comment: i know how to set keyboard shortcut... the problem is what command i should use for it! u can see it in title of my question

Comment: see the second row of my post.. /[path to where you unzipped the tar archive]/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach; the executable is "start-tor-browser"